# Analyzing and Comparing 2 Lists

Tags: c#, compare

i know this sounds like im asking for a spoon to be fed to me, but i am really fuzzed up and stuck on formulating several logics but still can't find the real deal.

my current system's goal is to analyze a student's grade and exam results to assess which college major is fit for him.

i have completed almost all of the system's functionality except the equation for this one.

assuming that

```
I  = Grades Result
II = Examination Result

A = Major A
B = Major B
C = Major C
```

so the table would look something like

```
   | A  |  B  |  C  |
---------------------
I  |    |     |     |
---------------------
II |    |     |     |
```

i need to formulate a result where i can assess several possible scenarios, like:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |
---------------------
I  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
---------------------
II |  1  |  3  |  2  |
```

in the table about, `Major A` had a rank of both `1` on `I` and `II`. So without further equations, the student is best to pick `Major A`.

and, in:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |
---------------------
I  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
---------------------
II |  3  |  2  |  1  |
```

`Major B` had a rank of both `2` on `I` and `II`. So like the first example in which the student got a stable result on both `I` and `II`, the student is best to pick `Major B`.

here:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |
---------------------
I  |  3  |  2  |  1  |
---------------------
II |  3  |  2  |  1  |
```

all three `Majors` have stable results in both `I` and `II`. But, in terms of ranking, `Major C` had the highest post so the student is off picking `Major C`.

and this is the trickiest part for me:

```
   |  A  |  B  |  C  |
---------------------
I  |  1  |  2  |  3  |
---------------------
II |  2  |  1  |  3  |
```

`Major C` is the only one that had a stable result result. But given that it's post is `3`, `Major C` is out of the equation. and therefore, a calculation will be performed. Where:

```
I =  60%
II = 40%

so 

Major A will be ((0.6 x 1) + (0.4 x 2)) = 1.4
Major B will be ((0.6 x 2) + (0.4 x 1)) = 1.6
```

Thus given in the equation, `Major A` had a higher ranking result over `Major B`. So the student will be given `Major A` as the top pick for Majors

---

i am really really really having a hard time thinking of a way to translate the equation and idea to a code where i will be utilizing two `List<>`. One for `I` and one for `II`.

so if someone could really really pick me up here, i would greatly appreciate it. i've ran out of idea to spare with this one. thank you

i have below code written and i know it is as ugly as it can be.

```
List<Ranking> Rank = new List<Ranking>();

// if all results are distinct to each other OR if all results are equal
if(
    (ExamResult[0].MajorResult != GradeResult[0].MajorResult && ExamResult[1].MajorResult != GradeResult[1].MajorResult && ExamResult[2].MajorResult != GradeResult[2].MajorResult)
  ||
    (ExamResult[0].MajorResult == GradeResult[0].MajorResult && ExamResult[1].MajorResult == GradeResult[1].MajorResult && ExamResult[2].MajorResult == GradeResult[2].MajorResult)
  )
{
    Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() + GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() });
    Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() + GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() });
    Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() + GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() });
}

// if one of the three is equal
if(ExamResult[0].MajorResult == GradeResult[0].MajorResult || ExamResult[1].MajorResult == GradeResult[1].MajorResult || ExamResult[2].MajorResult == GradeResult[2].MajorResult)
{
    var LowestRank1 = ExamResult.OrderBy(x => x.MajorResult).Last();
    var LowestRank2 = GradeResult.OrderBy(x => x.MajorResult).Last();

    var HighestRank1 = ExamResult.OrderBy(x => x.MajorResult).First();
    var HighestRank2 = GradeResult.OrderBy(x => x.MajorResult).First();

    if((ExamResult[0].MajorResult == LowestRank1.MajorResult) && (GradeResult[0].MajorResult == LowestRank2.MajorResult))
    {
        Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = (ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.4) + (GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.6) });
        Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = (ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.4) + (GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.6) });
    }

    if((ExamResult[1].MajorResult == LowestRank1.MajorResult) && (GradeResult[1].MajorResult == LowestRank2.MajorResult))
    {
        Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = (ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.4) + (GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.6) });
        Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = (ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.4) + (GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 3).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.6) });
    }

    if((ExamResult[2].MajorResult == LowestRank1.MajorResult) && (GradeResult[2].MajorResult == LowestRank2.MajorResult))
    {
        Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = (ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.4) + (GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 1).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.6) });
        Rank.Add(new Ranking() { Name = ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorDescription).Single(), Value = (ExamResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.4) + (GradeResult.Where(x => x.MajorID == 2).Select(x => x.MajorResult).Single() * 0.6) });
    }
}
```

Comment: Im having trouble following your logic, so you only want to compare using the formula if the highest ranked "stable" candidate received 3s? Otherwise stable should outrank unstable?

Comment: i think if i can explain this the best that i can. is to rank the Grade and Exam of the Student and get the ranking of the three Majors which he can take. Where 1 is the best pick and 3 as the worst

Comment: Yeah, multiply each score by its scale and then select the lowest score for the given student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that

```
I  = Grades Result
II = Examination Result

A = Major A
B = Major B
C = Major C
```

you can calculate points for every major like:

```
((1 << (A.I - 1)) * 0.6) + ((1 << (A.II - 1)) * 0.4)
```

the same for major B and C. the lower the best.

```
First table:
A = 1;
B = 1.8;
C = 3.2;
Second:
A = 2.2;
B = 2;
C = 2.8;
Third:
A = 4;
B = 2;
C = 1;
Fourth:
A = 1.4;
B = 1.6;
C = 4;
```

this works only because you said the best result is 1. you can shift only by 7 on int and 15 on int64.

let me know if you have Grade or Examination results > of 7 or 15